Why is my SSIS package no running in 64 bit mode on VS2022?
I have an ssis project that is running perfectly on SQL Server 2019 using x32 bits and i need to run it on x64. I have installed the OLEDB drivers, sql server on x64 both 2019 and 2022 and when i tried to execute it shows this error locally. Also im using Excel connectors in the project and they are installed on x64 as well.
===================================
Failed to start project (Microsoft Visual Studio)
===================================
No se puede crear un host de depuración para el paquete. (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)
Ubicación del programa:
en Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsPackageDebugger.LaunchVsDebugger(Boolean isRemoteTest, IVsDebugger iVsDebugger, DataTransformationsProjectConfigurationOptions options)
en Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsPackageDebugger.ValidateAndRunDebugger(Int32 flags, IOutputWindow outputWindow, DataTransformationsProjectConfigurationOptions options)
en Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectDebugger.LaunchDtsPackage(Int32 launchOptions, ProjectItem startupProjItem, DataTransformationsProjectConfigurationOptions options)
en Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectDebugger.LaunchDtsPackage(Int32 launchOptions, DataTransformationsProjectConfigurationOptions options)
en Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectDebugger.Launch(Int32 launchOptions, DataTransformationsProjectConfigurationOptions options)
===================================
No se puede comunicar con el proceso de host de depuración. No se ha registrado la interfaz IDtsHost. (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)
Ubicación del programa:
en Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DebugEngine.DebugEngine.LaunchDtsDebugHost(Process& process, Boolean run64bit)
en Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DebugEngine.DtsProgramNode.CreateRuntimePackageInternal(IDtsHost& host, Process& process, Package& dtsPackage)
Ive tried reinstalling the softwares, drivers, individuall
